# How can I change color with append Div?

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

I can't change color with append div dynamically. I want change default color of div, in red.

My HTML markup is:

```
<div id="risultato"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var result= document.getElementById('risultato');
result.style.color = "red";
result.innerHTML+= <a href="www.google.com">
```

but google.com have blue color not red.

I also tried with css:

```
<style>
#risultato {
    margin-left: 18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}   
</style>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Few issues. `<a href="www.google.com">` needs to be in quotes. Also, it needs the closing `</a>` tag as well as some content. E.g. `result.innerHTML+= '<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>'`. But that aside, links have default styling that you'd need to override

Comment: The short answer is [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). The slightly longer version is the `a` tag has its own default styling you need to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var result= document.getElementById('risultato');
result.style.color = "red";
result.innerHTML+= '<a style="color:green" href="www.google.com">google</a>'
```

```css
both js and css are basically fine.  your innerHTML statement needs some fine tuning.
```

```html
<div id="risultato">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<style>
#risultato a {
color:red;
}   
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get the div
var result = document.getElementById('risultato');
// Append the element to the div and give it a class
result.innerHTML += "<a class='link' href='www.google.com'>Google</a>";
// Get the element (link)
let resultLink = document.querySelector('#risultato a');
// Style it
resultLink.style.color = 'red';
```

```css
#risultato a{
  font-size:17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="risultato"></div>
```